# Repartitioning Skewed Dataframes in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a bit of a question around PySpark.

After aggregating, I have really skewed data (some partitions are massive).

If I repartition; it takes ages, as the dataset is huge.

Is repartitioning the best option to re-align these partition sizes?

If I were to join this to another dataset; should I repartition before doing the join?

Any thoughts on best practice would be really appreciated!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you identified what causes data skewness? Maybe you have a small set of dominant keys in which case repartitioning won't be very helpful. For joining, you can use broadcast join if the other dataset is small, use iterative joining (by dividing into small chunks)  or add salt to the join keys. See [Optimizing Skew Join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#optimizing-skew-join).

Comment: Yeah, it's a UK company, but there are transactions elsewhere; so the dominant partition is the country code. I did think about salting to create new keys like UK1, UK2, UK3... but its a very time consuming operation , so i am not sure it's the best approach